# While opening XML file in excel using C# extra columns appear

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I am trying to open an xml file in excel, following is the code;

```
    string exeFilePath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath;
    string excelFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFilePath);
    string path = excelFilePath + "\\shiporder.xml";

    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = true;

    Excel.Workbooks books = excelApp.Workbooks;
    Excel.Workbook book = books.OpenXML(path);
```

Now when I run the above code, I see extra columns inside the excel file in the start, I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

The following is the XML file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

The following is the XSD file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Kindly tell me how can this issue be solved?

Currently the excel file looks like this;

```
/shiporder                                                  
/@orderid   /@orderid/#agg  /@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation /item/note  /item/price /item/price/#agg    /item/quantity  /item/quantity/#agg /item/title /orderperson    /shipto/address /shipto/city    /shipto/country /shipto/name
889923      889923          shiporder.xsd   Special Edition 10.9    10.9    1   1   Empire Burlesque    John Smith  Langgt 23   4000 Stavanger  Norway  Ola Nordmann
     889923               shiporder.xsd     9.9 9.9 1   1   Hide your heart John Smith  Langgt 23   4000 Stavanger  Norway  Ola Nordmann
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what your excel file currently looks like.

Comment: And what would you expect? It looks like it works as designed...